# Click Anchor in modal close modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

How to when I click to open modal show the modal content. i click to anchor close the modal and srcoll to anchor id.

```css
#Content {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <a href="#Content">The Content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="Content">
The Content
</div>
```

Any idea for help me. Thanks!

Comment: Why  `margin-top: 1200px;`?????????

Comment: i have add margin to srcoll down whent click anchor bro? optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hide the modal, wait for the animation to complete, and then scroll to the item.

You can optionally animate the scroll with `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#Content').offset().top)});`

```js
function onContentClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').one('hidden.bs.modal', () =>
    window.scrollTo(0, $('#Content').offset().top));
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
```

```css
#Content {
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 1000px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <a href="#Content" onClick="onContentClick(event)">The Content</a>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div id="Content">
The Content
</div>
```